# How can I call a function from a Shared Library

Tags: java, c++, c, linux, java-native-interface

I have a Shared Library loading in my system (Java + Linux).

```
System.loadLibrary("mylib");
```

I want call a java function from mylib, exemple:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_absoluta_web_AW_10001_Funcao3(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    javaFUnction();
printf("Here...\n");
    return;
}
```

It's possible?

Comment: This may help - http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Call_a_function_in_a_shared_library

Answer (score 0):

You would use

`env->CallVoidMethod(obj, methodID)`

where you obtain methodID with something like

`jmethodID = env->GetMethodID(classID, "javaFuntion", signature)`

where classID is the id of the class, and signature is the signature of your function. You can get the signature using javap. All this is well documented. You should be able to take it from there.